# Is there a way to retrieve a username or file from browser cache or cookies?

Tags: browser, macos-catalina

Several months ago I made an account on an online shop and did one transaction. For some reason I cannot remember the email I used. Is there a way to retrieve this information somewhere in my browser cache or something? I opened a file within that account, is that also somehow retrievable? I am on MacOS Catalina by the way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in Keychain.

You can access it from two places…

Safari Prefs > Passwords
or
Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access

Type a few letters of the site address into the search box;
Passwords: click the item
Keychain Access: double click the item, then check the Show Password box, authorise & it should be there.

Keychain Access stays open longer, Safari's passwords re-locks rather irritatingly after just a few seconds.

If it's not in either of those, then you'll have to go through the site's forgotten password route.